# Getting null pixels during soil texture analysis

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, spatial-statistics, soilgrids, soil

I am using 'OpenLandMap/SOL/SOL_TEXTURE-CLASS_USDA-TT_M/v02'

band 'b0'

when I run my analysis, why I am getting null pixels.

**Output**

```
Object (5 properties)

4: 67274

6: 963

7: 280852

9: 144241

null: 59043
```

**My code:**

```
var soil_class = ee.Image("OpenLandMap/SOL/SOL_TEXTURE-CLASS_USDA-TT_M/v02")
              .select('b0').clip(roi)
              .rename('soil');
             
Map.addLayer(soil_class);


var pixelCountStats = soil_class.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram().unweighted(),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 250,
    maxPixels: 1e10
    });
  print(pixelCountStats);
```

What do the null pixels represent and how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, null pixels indicate NoData or missing data. If you inspect from the Google Earth Engine editor you can see the water bodies show null pixels or masked value whereas others show a certain value. Hence, the null values can be related to the waterbodies.

[image]

From the above screenshot, an example is shown for the inspector tool. The cross mark is the place where the inspector tool was kept and it shows a masked value. The basemap shows a river. Additionally, there are some lands not covered by the data. They have null pixels as well.